# template class with a single method specialized in C++

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I only have an hpp file for a school assignment in C++ (I am not allowed to add a cpp file, declaration and implementation should be both written in the file).

I wrote this code inside it:

```
template<class T>
class Matrix
{
   void foo()
   {
       //do something for a T variable.
   }
};
```

I would like to add another `foo` method, but this `foo()` will be specialized for only an `<int>`.
I have read in some places that I need to declare a new specialization class for this to work. But what I want is that the specialized `foo` will lie just beneath the original `foo`, so it will look like this:

```
template<class T>
class Matrix
{
   void foo(T x)
   {
       //do something for a T variable.
   }
   template<> void foo<int>(int x)
   {
       //do something for an int variable.
   }
};
```

- Why am I getting an error for this syntax ("expected unqualified-id before '<' token")?
- Why isn't this possible?
- How can I fix this without declaring a new specialized class?

Thanks

Comment: `foo` isn't a template. `Matrix` is.

Comment: You are getting the error because this violates C++ syntax. You can't specialize only a member of a template class but rather you need to specialize the whole class.

Comment: But i have lot's of other functions in that class, so do i have to copy-paste all these functions to the new "int" class? sounds like a terrible code repetition.

Comment: @40two: You can specialize only the method: see T.C. answer.

Comment: You can also make the method itself a template, and specialize the method itself. When are the exact requirements?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`foo` isn't a template. It's a member function of a template. Thus `foo<int>` is meaningless. (Also, explicit specializations must be declared at namespace scope.)

You can explicitly specialize a member function of a particular implicit instantiation of a class template:

```
template<class T>
class Matrix
{
   void foo(T x)
   {
       //do something for a T variable.
   }
};

// must mark this inline to avoid ODR violations
// when it's defined in a header
template<> inline void Matrix<int>::foo(int x)
{
     //do something for an int variable.
}
```

Comment: Awesome. but, is that allowed to write this line : template<> void Matrix<int>::foo(int x) inside an hpp file ? cause i usually see it only in cpp files.

Comment: @user2630165 Yes, it's fine...you'll need to make it `inline` though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the original foo method as a template, and actually there is no need for your class to be a template, only the method:

```
class Matrix
{
    template<typename T> void foo(T x)
    {
        //do something for a T variable.
    }
    template<> void foo<int>(int x)
    {
        //do something for an int variable.
    }
};
```

UPDATE: The code works only in Visual Studio. Here is a code that should work elsewhere too:

```
class Matrix
{
    template<typename T> void foo(T x)
    {
        //do something for a T variable.
    }
};

template<> void Matrix::foo<int>(int x)
{
    //do something for an int variable.
}
```

Comment: Doesn't compile: `error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'class Matrix'`...

Comment: That's right, the code I wrote is only compatible with visual studio. I added a C++ compliant code that should work with GCC too.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that OP needs `Matrix` to be a template.

Comment: OP wrote explicitly that they need another foo method specialized for `int`.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that a `Matrix` class will need to store some data whose type may vary...