# C++ template inheritance 2 arguments

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, arguments, containers

is it possible to inherit everything from template class and just rewrite some of it's functions specialized to int, double or float?

Is there a way to write something similar to this?

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
class Container<int, N> : public Container<T, N> {

};
```

Comment: Please give more details exactly what You want. And how You want to use the end classes. The answer will be different depending on the specific use cases.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [template class with a single method specialized in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25724360/template-class-with-a-single-method-specialized-in-c)

Comment: No, it's not possible as described.  You're simultaneously specifying that `Container<int, N>` only has one base, but - using the template mechanism - you're also specifying that it derives from every instantiation of `Container<T, N>` - which is an unbounded number of base classes.

Answer (score 2):

No, you need to use a different name.

```
template<class T, size_t N>
struct ContainerBase:std::array<T,N> {
  // some methods here
};

template<class T, size_t N>
struct Container:ContainerBase<T,N> {
  // inherit any constructors:
  using ContainerBase<T,N>::ContainerBase;
};
template<size_t N>
struct Container<int, N>:ContainerBase<int,N> {
  using ContainerBase<int,N>::ContainerBase;
  // overload (not override) methods here
};
```